# Basis of the Lie Algebra of a Group

Tags: group-theory, linear-algebra

It is known that the Lie algebra of a group is a vector space. The question i have is this: Is there a way to find a basis of the Lie algebra of the group? Also, if i have a set of matrices that belong to the group, can i find the basis of its Lie algebra using the matrices?

Comment: These are two questions in pure mathematics whose answers are too broad for a website like this. What have you read about this subject?

Comment: Study the group around the identity, and parameterize the first order increments. Do it for the rotation group you have presumably mastered, and you'll get the point.

Comment: How to find a basis for a vector space: pick $n$ vectors at random - are they a basis? If not, throw some away and pick new ones. Repeat until you have a basis.

Comment: what do you mean by "calculate the basis"? finding *a* basis?

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this maths question?

Answer (score 0):

I think in general the answer to your question is 'yes', although it depends on the group as well.

For a Lie algebra you need both the vector space **and** a Lie bracket (an operation that takes two vector fields and assigns a third one to it). If you know the Lie bracket of your group, you *could* be able to find the vector space elements.

A 2D example on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra#Two_dimensions) shows that if your Lie bracket is $[x,y]=y$, meaning that the commutator of the generators x and y gives y. With the Lie bracket you can then derive a general form for x and y (see Wikipedia).

The generators are your Lie group basis because they can generate your Lie group (see [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65141/do-generators-belong-to-the-lie-group-or-the-lie-algebra?rq=1)).

I hope this answers your question, it has been a while since I took a class on Lie algebra, but I also vaguely remember being able to find the generators using homomorphisms to other groups, maybe that is worth looking into as well...

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Just to understand it for a specific group,let's say we have the SU(3). The generators of the Lie algebra of SU(3) are $T_a={\lambda}_a/2$ with $\lambda_a$ being the Gell-Mann matrices. Are the $T_a$ the basis?

Comment: Yes, look for example at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_constants) Wikipedia page: _For a Lie algebra, the basis vectors are termed the generators of the algebra, and the product is given by the Lie bracket._ It also gives the example of su(3).